# awk - set RS from the input file

Tags: awk

I've got a file where the first few bites define some of the attributes of the file.

The 9th bite is the record separator. So the records are not separated by `\n` but by whatever is on the 9th bite.

I need to read this file, set `RS` and then read the file "again" but now separated by this new record separator.

Input file (here the record separator is `'`):

```
UNA:+,? 'UNB+UNOC:3+4042805000102:14+4016001000655:14+201231:0206+EC33218279A++TL'UNH+1+MSCONS:D:04B:UN:2.3'BGM+7+EC33218279A-1+9'DTM+137:202012310206:203'RFF+Z13:13018'NAD+MS+4042805000102::9'NAD+MR+4016001000655::9'UNS+D'NAD+DP'LOC+172+DE00108108359V0000000000000088446'DTM+163:202012300000?+01:303
```

awk program would be something like:

```
{ RS=substr($0, 9, 1) }
{ do magic }
```

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: Can the 9th character ever also appear in the first 8 characters (e.g. `U'A:+,? 'UNB+UN...`) and, if so, what would the output look like given that?

Comment: Can there be newlines in your input file or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you never expect the 9th char to also appear in the first 8 chars, or if it does you don't want it treated as an RS in that context, then you could use this 1-pass approach using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='.{9}' 'NR==1{$0=substr(RT,1,8); RS=substr(RT,9,1)} 1' file
UNA:+,?
UNB+UNOC:3+4042805000102:14+4016001000655:14+201231:0206+EC33218279A++TL
UNH+1+MSCONS:D:04B:UN:2.3
BGM+7+EC33218279A-1+9
DTM+137:202012310206:203
RFF+Z13:13018
NAD+MS+4042805000102::9
NAD+MR+4016001000655::9
UNS+D
NAD+DP
LOC+172+DE00108108359V0000000000000088446
DTM+163:202012300000?+01:303
```

Answer (score 4):

A 2 pass `gnu awk` would do that as we need to set multi-char `RS`:

```bash
awk -v RS='.{9}' 'FNR == NR {RS=substr(RT,9,1); nextfile} 1' file file

UNA:+,?
UNB+UNOC:3+4042805000102:14+4016001000655:14+201231:0206+EC33218279A++TL
UNH+1+MSCONS:D:04B:UN:2.3
BGM+7+EC33218279A-1+9
DTM+137:202012310206:203
RFF+Z13:13018
NAD+MS+4042805000102::9
NAD+MR+4016001000655::9
UNS+D
NAD+DP
LOC+172+DE00108108359V0000000000000088446
DTM+163:202012300000?+01:303
```

---

Thanks to Ed for suggesting this any version `awk` solution:

```bash
awk 'NR==FNR {
   if (!f) {
      rec = rec sep $0
      sep = RS
      if (length(rec) >= 9) {
         RS = substr(rec,9,1)
         f = 1
      }
   }
   next
}
1' file file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can kinda cheat with a function like this :

- `caveat : this gets you the n-th` ***`byte`***`, not necessarily n-th character`

.

```
 {m,g}awk 'BEGIN {
     1      _=__=___=_<_
     1      RS = getNthByte(ARGV[ARGC-!_], 9)
          }
 13929783  {
 13929783   ___+=length($_)
 13929783    __+=NF
          }
    function getNthByte(_,____,__,___)
    {
     1      gsub("\47", "&\\\\&&", _)
     1      ___ = RS
     1       RS = "^$"
     1      (__ = "ghead -c "(____)" \47"(_)"\47 | gtail -c 1 ") | getline _
     1      close(__)
     1      RS = ___
     1      return _
    
    } END { print _=NR,__,___+_ }' "${file}"
```

> ```
> 13929783 20069465 160950672
> ```